# How to compare integers with accuracy in Python?

Tags: python, colors, integer, tuples, compare

I have a tuple for color. For example, (218, 174, 84). The task is to increase each red, green and blue value by some increment and then compare it with an accuracy 1. How can I do this in *Pythonic way?* Do you know best practices?

Color: (218, 174, 84)
Increment: 5

For red value 222, 223, 224 is legal. Green: 178, 179, 180, Blue: 88, 89, 90.

Comment: Whats an example of an *illegal* color?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare with accuracy 1"?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. But if you need - (221, 177, 87) is illegal.

Comment: Make a dictionary with lists of all valid tuples for each color name then you can check if a *color* is valid for any color name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def valid_color(orig_color, new_color, increment):
    return all(c1 + increment - 1 <= c2 <= c1 + increment + 1 for c1, c2 in zip(orig_color, new_color))
```

Use `zip()` to pair up the components of the original color and the color you're comparing with. Then use comparison operators to test that each component is valid.

Comment: More elegant and for different increments:
`return all(math.isclose(c1 + inc, c2, abs_tol=1) for c1, c2, inc in zip(orig_color, new_color, increment))`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use python magic and use just `==`, you could do:

```
class Color(tuple):
    def __init__(self, *_, inc=0):
        self.inc = inc

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return all(c1 + self.inc - 1 <= c2 <= c1 + self.inc + 1 for (c1, c2) in zip(self, other))


c = Color((1, 2, 3), inc=5)
c2 = Color((5, 6, 8))
print(c == c2)
```